# Check if a field/propertry exists in a variable of type object

Tags: php, object, zend-search-lucene

I am using Zend_Search_Lucene, to index my website. My site indexes are not entirely similar. Some have, few fields, and some have many fields. I am trying to create a similar index through different types of table, that's why i am encountering this kind of error.

Now, when I display the result. I call some fields, which are not present in all the result which generates the error. i tried to check it with `isset` but it seems it totally skips the row.

```
foreach ($hits as $hit) {
    $content .= '<div class="searchResult">';
      $content .= '<h2>';           
        $title = array();
        if(isset($hit -> name)) $title[] = $hit -> name;
        if(isset($hit -> title)) $title[] = $hit -> title;
            // This is the part where i get fatal error.
        $content .= implode(" &raquo; ",$title);
      $content .= '</h2>';
      $content .= '<p>'.$this->content.'</p>';
    $content .= '</div>';
}
```

How to check if there is anything such as `$hit -> name` is present in `$hit`

Comment: Does it skip the row or do you get a PHP error? You seem indecisive.

Comment: Of course error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception' with message 'Field name "name" not found in document`

Comment: I just solved the problem, but keep in mind that if you had not given the exact error message I would never have been able to. In the future, please post *all relevant messages* when asking the question. Don't leave people guessing, it makes it harder for *you* to get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem you are experiencing is very very specific and has to do with the `Zend_Lucene_Search` implementation, not the field/property exist check in general.**

In your loop, `$hit` is an object of class [`Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryHit`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Search/Lucene/Search/QueryHit.php). When you write the expression `$hit->name`, the object calls the [magic `__get` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) to give you a "virtual property" named `name`. It is this magic function that throws the exception if the value to be supplied does not exist.

Normally, when a class implements `__get` as a convenience it should also implement `__isset` as a convenience (otherwise you cannot really use `isset` on such virtual properties, as you have found out the hard way). Since this particular class does not implement `__isset` as IMHO it should, you will never be able to get the `name` "property" blindly without triggering an exception if the relevant data does not exist.

`property_exists` and all other forms of reflection will also not help since we are not talking about a real property here.

The proper way to solve this is a little roundabout:

```
$title = array();
$names = $hit->getDocument()->getFieldNames();
if(in_array('name', $names)) $title[] = $hit -> name;
if(in_array('title',$names)) $title[] = $hit -> title;
```

All said, I 'd consider this a bug in ZF and probably file a report, asking for the `__isset` magic method to be implemented appropriately on the types it should be.

Comment: `getFieldNames` do not return associative array. I have corrected your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. @Starx, I didn't knew you knew Zend Framework too.

Comment: @mrN, I am also a newBie at this. But, try me before you post at SO. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try [property_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).

```
foreach ($hits as $hit) {
    $content .= '<div class="searchResult">';
      $content .= '<h2>';           
        $title = array();
        if(property_exists($hit, 'name')) $title[] = $hit -> name;
        if(property_exists($hit, 'title')) $title[] = $hit -> title;
            // This is the part where i get fatal error.
        $content .= implode(" &raquo; ",$title);
      $content .= '</h2>';
      $content .= '<p>'.$this->content.'</p>';
    $content .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: $hit, is not a class, its just a variable of type Object

Comment: I am not familiar with Zend, but it should work on any object from PHP's stdClass. I tested with:

`$hit = new stdClass();
$hit->name = 'foo';
echo property_exists($hit, 'name') ? 't' : 'f';

> t`

Comment: It won't work correctly if the property does not exist in the first place but it is implemented using `__get` instead.

Comment: @Jon I see. Thanks for the insight into this Zend class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reflection to query what fields the object has and build your content in a more programmatic way.  this is good if you have a ton of fields.

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass( get_class( $hit ) );
foreach( $reflector->getProperties() as $property  ) {
    if( in_array( $property->getName(), $SEARCH_FIELDS )
        $title[] = $property->getValue( $hit );
}
```

more info here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 0):

```
# Verify if exists
$hits = $index->find('id_field:100');
if (isset($hits[0])) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

isset will work if you simply convert your object to an array first.

```
<?php
class Obj {
    public function GetArr() {
        return (array)$this;
    }
    static public function GetObj() {
        $obj = new Obj();
        $obj->{'a'} = 1;
        return $obj;
    }
}

$o = \Obj::GetObj();
$a = $o->GetArr();
echo 'is_array: ' . (\is_array($a) ? 1 : 0) . '<br />';
if (\is_array($a)) {
    echo '<pre>' . \print_r($a, \TRUE) . '</pre><br />';
}
echo '<pre>' . \serialize($o) . '</pre>';
?>
```